# Django ORM JOIN's

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have a table '**Comments**' and inside field the 'user', I would get in addition to the profile **Profile** in the same query. Currently I have something like that

```
comments = models.Comment.objects.select_related('author__profile').filter(post=article)
```

Unfortunately I can not retrieve information about profile, I can only get to it through

```
comment.author._profile_set_cache
```

Any ideas to make it look nice like?

```
comment.author.profile
```

Answer (score 0):

If the 'author' is from the contrib.auth User model, then you don't have a FK to the UserProfile. It is a "reverse one-to-one". Fortunately, django is able to navigate a reverse one-to-one using "select_related", so the query is actually retrieving the fields (you can check it by using

```
print models.Comment.objects.select_related('author__profile').filter(post=article).query
```

The way to get the profile of a user is with the `get_profile()` method:

```
print comment.author.get_profile()
```

As the profile data is already cached (that's why the _profile_set_cache is for), getting the object means no additional query.

Comment: Ok, thanks. My friend did a profile appeal by a ForeignKey, not OneToOneField...;/ After changing the OneToOneField works perfectly.